# De Morgan's law proof: Equalities or Subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Common proofs of de Morgan's law seem to go like this:

$$(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c \\ x \in (A \cup B)^c \iff x \notin (A \cup B)
\\\iff x \notin A \ and \ x \notin B \ \\\iff x \in A^c \ and \ x \in B^c \\\iff x \in A^c \cap B^c  $$

Read from top to bottom, the common conclusion is that $$  (A \cup B)^c \subseteq A^c \cap B^c \\
$$ and from there on one can basically go the other way around and proof that
$$
A^c \cap B^c \subseteq (A \cup B)^c 
$$
And having proved that both are subsets from each other, on can replace the subset symbol by a equal sign, and thereby land at the de Morgan's law.

But why can we not just conclude that both sides are equal right when we have $$ x \in A^c \cap B^c$$
and thus say $$ \implies (A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c $$

It seems to me that one could just reverse the subset signs anyway without doing anything illogical.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do exactly as you say: if you show that $x \in X \Leftrightarrow x \in Y$, then you can immediately conclude $X = Y$

Comment: Thanks alot! But what confuses me here is: suppose that set X = {x, y} and set Y = {x, z}, then x being an element of X and Y would not imply that X and Y are equal (since the elements y and z are only in one of each). Or do I make a mistake here?

Comment: @Jan-MartinGebert The $x$ is supposed to be an arbitrarily chosen element. Think of it like a variable. So if $X=\{ 1,2 \}$, then when $x \in X$, we have that $x=1$ or $x =2$

Comment: So  " ∈ " means "all possible elements of X", right?